# Visual Studio Report Designer change line size dinamically

Tags: visual-studio, report, rdlc

I'm creating a report with some `TextBox`(Expandable) and `Lines`. What I'm wondering is if that's a way to have the `Lines` expand based on the length of the text in the `TextBox`

This is my report with the text on only one row:

[image]

This is when my TextBox expand in multiple rows:

[image: img]

Is there a way to have the line on the right to expand?

Comment: Is there any other controls (or table columns) on the right?

Comment: Yes there are other TextBox and Lines in the report.

Comment: You may need to re-think design of your report then. Unfortunately, the textbox cannot "grow" horizontally and push other elements to the right (what a mess it would be!), it will have lines added instead. If this text box is inside the table cell, you could merge all the columns to the right and then you would have two options: concatenate all the text in one field and display it all in that merged cell, or display the data of the other elements below your "expandable" text box instead.